# Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to R$ be $f(x)=\max\{x^2,\cos x\}$.Prove $f(x)$ attains minimum at $x_0$ and is a sulution to $x^2=\cos x$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I try to write $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}|x^2-\cos x|$ and use the Extreme Value Theorem to show that $x_0$ exists in $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, but I don't know how to show the seconde part

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)$ is continuous and $[0, \pi /2]$ is compact, therefore it's image: $I = \{f(x) : 0 \le x \le \pi/2\}$ is compact too.

Being compact in $\mathbb R$ is equivalent to being bounded and closed, therefore we know that there is $x_0$ such that $(\forall y \in I)(f(x_0) \le f(y))$.

The function $x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$, $x \mapsto \cos x$ is decreasing. We know that $\cos(0) = 1 > 0 = 0^2$ and $\cos(\pi/2) = 0 < \pi^2 / 4$. Therefore there is exactly one $x$ such that $\cos x = x^2$. Can you show that $x = x_0$ will do the job?

Comment: Thanks. But in fact I know how to do the first part, I want to ask about the second part. I just updated my question

Comment: @zhazha, I've edited my answer.